# ObjectInputStream doesnt work as expected

Tags: java, android, ioexception

I'm trying to save an object to a file and read it again, here is the code I'm using:

This code to store the object to a file: (called in onDestroy)

```
    private void serializeModulesManager() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("modules.txt",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(Module.values());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code to read the object from the file: (called in onCreate())

```
private void restoreModulesManager() {
        FileInputStream fileIn;
        Module[] arr = null;
        try {

            fileIn = openFileInput("modules.txt");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn); 

            arr = (Module[]) in.readObject(); // "in" object is empty so I cant read anything from it.. I get an EOFException and get to IOException

            for (Module c : arr) {
                Module.valueOf(c.name()).serilize(c);
            }

            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the restoreModulesManager() function: When I close the application from the task manager, or restart the device, the "ObjectInputStream in" object is empty so I cant read anything from it in the next line..

Any idea why is this happening?

stacktrace:

```
12-16 20:53:40.395: W/System.err(18512): java.io.EOFException
12-16 20:53:40.415: W/System.err(18512):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:98)
12-16 20:53:40.415: W/System.err(18512):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.nextTC(ObjectInputStream.java:506)
12-16 20:53:40.425: W/System.err(18512):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:778)
12-16 20:53:40.425: W/System.err(18512):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
12-16 20:53:40.435: W/System.err(18512):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
12-16 20:53:40.435: W/System.err(18512):    at com.technion.coolie.CoolieActivity.restoreModulesManager(CoolieActivity.java:489)
12-16 20:53:40.445: W/System.err(18512):    at com.technion.coolie.CoolieActivity.onCreate(CoolieActivity.java:52)
12-16 20:53:40.445: W/System.err(18512):    at com.technion.coolie.skeleton.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
12-16 20:53:40.445: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
12-16 20:53:40.445: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 20:53:40.455: W/System.err(18512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
12-16 20:53:40.465: W/System.err(18512):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 20:53:40.465: W/System.err(18512):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 20:53:40.465: W/System.err(18512):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-16 20:53:40.465: W/System.err(18512):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-16 20:53:40.465: W/System.err(18512):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Firstly, given that this is binary data, I really *wouldn't* call the file "modules.txt" which implies that it's a text file. Now, what do your `openFileInput` and `openFileOutput` files look like? (Additionally, please don't "handle" exceptions like this... did you have any stack trace when writing the file?)

Comment: I didnt have any stack trace when writing to the file. I tried to open the file in my PC and they look weird in the text editor .. Here is what it looks like: http://pastebin.com/eN7mnMrD

Comment: Well yes, it *would* look odd in a text editor, because it's *not text*. It's a binary serialization format. But if the file exists, that's a start. Now, what exactly did you mean by "the object is empty"?

Comment: What I mean is that "in.readObject()" gives an EOFException.. so it looks like "in object" it empty or something..

Comment: Okay - there's nothing *obviously* wrong with the code, to be honest. Have you tried it in a small Java console app?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this in `onDestroy()` because there are cases where `onDestroy()` is never called. You should probably do this in `onPause()` because that is the only lifecycle event that is guaranteed to be called when your app is no longer in the foreground.

Also, `onDestroy()` is called so late in the lifecycle that you shouldn't be trying to do things like open files in there. In `onDestroy()` the only thing you should be doing is releasing resources (memory, files, etc.) that you have already allocated and ensuring that any background threads are shut down.

Comment: I tried calling it in onPause() but I still get the same behavior :(

Comment: Post the stacktrace you are getting.